# Recursively add dates until condition is met

Tags: r, purrr

I have a dataset as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

set.seed(2021)
df <- tibble(
  customer = seq(1:6),
  start_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                          as.Date('2020-12-31'),
                          by = "day"), 6),
  end_date = c(sample(seq(as.Date('2021-01-01'),
                          as.Date('2021-02-28'),
                          by = "day"), 3), NA, NA, NA))
```

```
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  customer start_date end_date  
     <int> <date>     <date>    
1        1 2020-06-14 2021-02-15
2        2 2020-08-18 2021-01-05
3        3 2020-03-10 2021-02-16
4        4 2020-07-10 NA        
5        5 2020-09-07 NA        
6        6 2020-04-11 NA
```

The objective of this function is to check whether each customer has churned at monthly intervals. This was done in [PostgreSQL here](https://github.com/carl24k/fight-churn/blob/master/listings/chap4/listing_4_4_observation_dates.sql) but I'm trying to translate it into R (preferably tidyverse).

These are the parameters:

```
obs_start <- as.Date(start_date)
obs_interval <- months(1)
lead_time <- weeks(1)

obs_date <- obs_start + obs_interval - lead_time
obs_end <- obs_date %m+% months(3)
```

For a given observation period (`obs_start` and `obs_end`), I wish to insert dates and check if a customer has churned. This insertion of dates will continue until

1. `obs_end` date is reached
2. a customer is flagged `is_churn = TRUE`, when `end_date >= obs_date` & end_date < next obs_date, in which the next obs_date isn't printed.

I did some digging and it seemed `purrr:accumulate()` could be used to recursively add dates with early termination using `done()`, but I'm quite lost on how to merge this into one (or several smaller) functions.

This is my desired output:

```
# A tibble: 22 x 5
   customer start_date end_date   obs_date   is_churn
      <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <lgl>   
 1        1 2020-06-14 2021-02-15 2020-11-17 FALSE   
 2        1 2020-06-14 2021-02-15 2020-12-18 FALSE   
 3        1 2020-06-14 2021-02-15 2021-01-18 FALSE   
 4        1 2020-06-14 2021-02-15 2021-02-15 TRUE    
 5        2 2020-08-18 2021-01-05 2020-11-17 FALSE   
 6        2 2020-08-18 2021-01-05 2020-12-18 TRUE    
 7        3 2020-03-10 2021-02-16 2020-11-17 FALSE   
 8        3 2020-03-10 2021-02-16 2020-12-18 FALSE   
 9        3 2020-03-10 2021-02-16 2021-01-18 FALSE   
10        3 2020-03-10 2021-02-16 2021-02-15 TRUE    
11        4 2020-07-10 NA         2020-11-17 FALSE   
12        4 2020-07-10 NA         2020-12-18 FALSE   
13        4 2020-07-10 NA         2021-01-18 FALSE   
14        4 2020-07-10 NA         2021-02-15 FALSE   
15        5 2020-09-07 NA         2020-11-17 FALSE   
16        5 2020-09-07 NA         2020-12-18 FALSE   
17        5 2020-09-07 NA         2021-01-18 FALSE   
18        5 2020-09-07 NA         2021-02-15 FALSE   
19        6 2020-04-11 NA         2020-11-17 FALSE   
20        6 2020-04-11 NA         2020-12-18 FALSE   
21        6 2020-04-11 NA         2021-01-18 FALSE   
22        6 2020-04-11 NA         2021-02-15 FALSE
```

Comment: Could you please show what would the desired output look like? Your objective to "to check whether each customer has churned at weekly intervals" seems vague to me.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny I have included desired output, and clarified the parameters, thanks! (Should be monthly not weekly intervals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question at least to some extent? It gives you the status (i.e. "not yet customer", "customer", "churned") for each date from the date series for every customer.

```
# date series by month starting from the min date until the max date
tibble(
  reference_date = seq(min(df$start_date), max(df$end_date, na.rm = T), by = "months")
) %>%
  # the original df is assigned to each date from the date series
  crossing(df) %>%
  # the status of the customer is checked for each date
  mutate(
    status = case_when(
      reference_date < start_date ~ "not yet customer",
      is.na(end_date) | reference_date <= end_date ~ "customer",
      T ~ "churned"
    )
  )
```

Comment: Yes it does, the use of crossing helped and I eventually answered this question with some creative use of filter here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597471/conditional-stopping-of-mutate