# Conditional stopping of mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that I wish to use `mutate` and `case_when`. However, I want to stop/filter the mutate after a certain logic is reached.

Data:

```
set.seed(2020)
df <- tibble(
  customer = seq(1:5),
  start_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                          as.Date('2020-12-31'),
                          by = "day"), 5),
  termination_date = c(sample(seq(as.Date('2020-06-01'),
                          as.Date('2021-02-28'),
                          by = "day"), 4), NA))
```

Parameters:

```
obs_start <- as.Date("2020-08-01")
obs_interval <- months(1)
lead_time <- weeks(1)

first_obs <- obs_start - lead_time
last_obs <- first_obs %m+% months(6)
obs_seq <- seq(first_obs, last_obs, by = "month")
```

`mutate` + `case_when`

```
df %>% 
  filter(termination_date > first_obs | is.na(termination_date)) %>% 
  crossing(obs_seq) %>% 
  mutate(is_churn = case_when(
    termination_date >= obs_seq &
      termination_date < (obs_seq + obs_interval) ~ "Yes",
    TRUE ~ "No"
  ))
```

```
   customer start_date termination_date obs_seq    is_churn
      <int> <date>     <date>           <date>     <chr>   
 1        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-07-25 No      
 2        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-08-25 No      
 3        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-09-25 No      
 4        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-10-25 No      
 5        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-11-25 No      
 6        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-12-25 No      
 7        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2021-01-25 No      
 8        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-07-25 No      
 9        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-08-25 No      
10        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-09-25 No      
11        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-10-25 Yes     
12        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-11-25 No      
13        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-12-25 No      
14        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2021-01-25 No      
15        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-07-25 No      
16        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-08-25 No      
17        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-09-25 No      
18        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-10-25 Yes     
19        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-11-25 No      
20        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-12-25 No      
21        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2021-01-25 No      
22        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-07-25 No      
23        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-08-25 No      
24        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-09-25 No      
25        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-10-25 No      
26        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-11-25 Yes     
27        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-12-25 No      
28        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2021-01-25 No      
29        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-07-25 No      
30        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-08-25 No      
31        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-09-25 No      
32        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-10-25 No      
33        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-11-25 No      
34        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-12-25 No      
35        5 2020-11-16 NA               2021-01-25 No
```

Within each group of `customer`, I want to remove all rows after `is_churn == "Yes"`
Below is the desired output:

```
# A tibble: 27 x 5
   customer start_date termination_date obs_seq    is_churn
      <int> <chr>      <chr>            <chr>      <chr>   
 1        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-07-25 No      
 2        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-08-25 No      
 3        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-09-25 No      
 4        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-10-25 No      
 5        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-11-25 No      
 6        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2020-12-25 No      
 7        1 2020-08-23 2021-02-28       2021-01-25 No      
 8        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-07-25 No      
 9        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-08-25 No      
10        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-09-25 No      
11        2 2020-03-27 2020-11-11       2020-10-25 Yes     
12        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-07-25 No      
13        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-08-25 No      
14        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-09-25 No      
15        3 2020-01-22 2020-11-17       2020-10-25 Yes     
16        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-07-25 No      
17        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-08-25 No      
18        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-09-25 No      
19        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-10-25 No      
20        4 2020-08-03 2020-12-15       2020-11-25 Yes     
21        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-07-25 No      
22        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-08-25 No      
23        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-09-25 No      
24        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-10-25 No      
25        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-11-25 No      
26        5 2020-11-16 NA               2020-12-25 No      
27        5 2020-11-16 NA               2021-01-25 No
```

Customer 1 is unchanged because the `termination_date` doesn't fall into the observation period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditionally `filter` rows for each `customer` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(termination_date > first_obs | is.na(termination_date)) %>% 
  tidyr::crossing(obs_seq) %>% 
  mutate(is_churn = case_when(
    termination_date >= obs_seq &
      termination_date < (obs_seq + obs_interval) ~ "Yes",
    TRUE ~ "No"
  )) %>%
  group_by(customer) %>%
  filter(if(any(is_churn == 'Yes')) row_number() <= match('Yes', is_churn) else TRUE) %>%
  ungroup 

#   customer start_date termination_date    obs_seq is_churn
#1         1 2020-08-23       2021-02-28 2020-07-25       No
#2         1 2020-08-23       2021-02-28 2020-08-25       No
#3         1 2020-08-23       2021-02-28 2020-09-25       No
#4         1 2020-08-23       2021-02-28 2020-10-25       No
#5         1 2020-08-23       2021-02-28 2020-11-25       No
#6         1 2020-08-23       2021-02-28 2020-12-25       No
#7         1 2020-08-23       2021-02-28 2021-01-25       No
#8         2 2020-03-27       2020-11-11 2020-07-25       No
#9         2 2020-03-27       2020-11-11 2020-08-25       No
#10        2 2020-03-27       2020-11-11 2020-09-25       No
#11        2 2020-03-27       2020-11-11 2020-10-25      Yes
#12        3 2020-01-22       2020-11-17 2020-07-25       No
#13        3 2020-01-22       2020-11-17 2020-08-25       No
#14        3 2020-01-22       2020-11-17 2020-09-25       No
#15        3 2020-01-22       2020-11-17 2020-10-25      Yes
#16        4 2020-08-03       2020-12-15 2020-07-25       No
#17        4 2020-08-03       2020-12-15 2020-08-25       No
#18        4 2020-08-03       2020-12-15 2020-09-25       No
#19        4 2020-08-03       2020-12-15 2020-10-25       No
#20        4 2020-08-03       2020-12-15 2020-11-25      Yes
#21        5 2020-11-16             <NA> 2020-07-25       No
#22        5 2020-11-16             <NA> 2020-08-25       No
#23        5 2020-11-16             <NA> 2020-09-25       No
#24        5 2020-11-16             <NA> 2020-10-25       No
#25        5 2020-11-16             <NA> 2020-11-25       No
#26        5 2020-11-16             <NA> 2020-12-25       No
#27        5 2020-11-16             <NA> 2021-01-25       No
```

For a `customer` if any value of `churn` is `'Yes'` select all rows before that including itself. If there is no `churn = 'Yes'` select all rows.